# Align a component to right in react native

Tags: react-native

In my application, I want to align a component (searchBar) to the right corner of my screen.
The mainWrapper has flexDirection RIGHT, so I tried to use justifyContent: "flex-end". But it did not work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";

import { DefaultButton , ClickableIcon} from "../../mixing/UI";
import { Search } from "../../config/images";

const width = Dimensions.get("window").width;

const chooseWorkoutHeader = props => (
  <View style={styles.mainWrapper}>

    <View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
      <DefaultButton
        buttonText={styles.buttonText}
        width={width * 0.3}
        backgroundColor="white"
        onPress={() => props.onClickPlaylists}>

        Playlists
      </DefaultButton>

      <DefaultButton
        buttonText={styles.buttonText}
        width={width * 0.3}
        backgroundColor="white"
        onPress={() => props.onClickSortBy}>

        Sort By
      </DefaultButton>
    </View>

    {/* <View style={styles.searchBar}> */}
      <ClickableIcon
        source={Search}
        height={35}
        width={35}
        style={styles.searchBar}
        // onIconPressed={() => {
        //   navigation.navigate("mainfeed");
        // }}
      />
    {/* </View> */}
</View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainWrapper: {
    borderWidth: 3,
    flexDirection: "row",
    padding: 10,  
    width: width,
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
  buttonWrapper: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    width: width * 0.62
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "gray"
  },
  searchBar: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
  }
});

export default chooseWorkoutHeader;
```

I tried alignSelf as well. But none of them worked. How to move the ClickableIcon which has styles as "searchBar" to the right of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by putting `flex: 1` for `buttonWrapper`

```
buttonWrapper: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    width: width * 0.62,
    flex: 1,  // Add this line
  }
```

You have two component inside `mainWrapper` (`buttonWrapper` and `ClickableIcon`). `flex: 1` will expand maximum with of `buttonWrapper` and leave space for `ClickableIcon` in right side.

Answer (score 1):

Do you tried adding this to your "mainWrapper":

display: "flex"

As far as i know "flex" only workings when you also set the display attribute